# MySQLdb Error: 'Unknown Database Python' using MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

When i run the code below in python 2.7.7, i get the error also below.

code:

```
    import MySQLdb

    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        user="root",
        passwd="mypassword",
        db="python"
    )
```

error:
`'_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'python'")'`

The database was made using MySQL Workbench and saved to the desktop (same location as python file) with the name python.
I'm not using Django or anything like that and can't find answers where the person isn't using it.
Please help.

Comment: Double check whether 'python' database exists at localhost:3306

Comment: You have installed MySQL Workbench, but have you installed `MySQL Server` ?? Look at your OS services.

Comment: yes MySQL Server is running on the localhost

Comment: Ok, so I think the answer I've given below is enough for you to create your database. Tell me in the answer comments if you have another problem or misunderstanding. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL Workbench produces a `.mwb` file which **is not a database**. This file is only a **Entity-Relationship schema** (which is very useful).

You have to export a `SQL create script` of your schema.

```
Menu File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE script
```

[image]

Then you execute this script (a `.sql` file) that will create your database.

For example, you can do it with :

- MySQL command
- phpMyAdmin
- MySQL workbench (through a connection)

### Create a MySQL Workbench connection :

[image]

### Copy and execute your SQL create script :

[image]

Your schema have to be like this in your case (**database name**) :

[image]

For your information a MySQL database is used through an IP/port, not through a file (SQLite is a file database for example, not MySQL).

Comment: I've exported it as highlighted but how do i do the rest? (as you can tell I'm no SQL expert) (I'd also rather not use phpMyAdmin if at all possible)

Comment: The graphical way : create a connection in MySQL Workbench. A shell way, launch the MySQL command line tool and execute/copy the exported file in it.

Comment: How do i get the connection to link to python?

Comment: Your python code is certainly OK (I don't know python by the way ;) ). The problem is that you have a MySQL server, but you have not created the `python` database you want to connect to in your python code. A MySQL Workbench connection is only used in MySQL Workbench ! ;) The SQL create script lets you create easyly your database, that's all.

Comment: I have added another image for you.

Comment: 1+ for reading out the totoally unobvious fact that the questioneer had a model and wanted it to access from Python. It's like thought-reading, wow! Btw: upgrade to MySQL Workbench 6.1.

Comment: I've certainly thought the same years ago, that's why ! ;)